# MediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(int timer) what happens when timer expires

Tags: android

According to the documentation, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setMaxDuration(int)

the recording stops when the timer expires.

By stop, do they mean it calls internally recorder.stop() and then restores the state the app was in before calling recorder.start()?

Comment: Could you find answer to you question?

Answer (score 42):

I have found that I have to implement MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener and manually stop the recording at that point.  Once that is done, the MediaRecorder goes back to the initial state and all of the normal setup has to be done again in order to start recording again.

```
public class VideoCapture extends Activity implements MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener { 

   public void startVideoRecording() {
      // Normal MediaRecorder Setup
      recorder.setMaxDuration(10000); // 10 seconds
      recorder.setOnInfoListener(this);
   }

   public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) { 
      if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
         Log.v("VIDEOCAPTURE","Maximum Duration Reached"); 
         mr.stop();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It is important not to forget **recorder.setOnInfoListener(this)**

Comment: or Use anonymous class recorder.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {

    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
     if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
      mr.stop();
     }

    }
   });

Answer (score 1):

This is handled by OpenCore internally, and the state of the recorder after reaching max duration is uninitialized, as it called stop(). You have setup the recorder again to use it further.

Comment: the problem is my application exits(the screen goes blank as soon the timer expires). That is not supposed to happen. It should gracefully stop recording and return to the preview state(the state it was in before I pressed record). is that possible?

Also is it possible, to handle it myself as in in onInfo
if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) { can I call my own function that calls recorder.stop() here?
}

Comment: I tried calling my own function as I mentioned but it crashed the same way as before

Comment: What is described above is what is supposed to happen but in my experience that isn't what actually happens.