# Android: Split video during capture

Tags: android, video, split, video-capture, video-recording

I am looking for solution to split video during capture to 5 minutes parts.
For example, during one hour trip (video capture) I would like to divide this video (during trip) to smaller videos 12 * 5 min = 1h. Not after stop capture, but in the meantime.

I would like to do something like video recorder.
Could you tell me what I need to use to do this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, you need to use:

```
MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED
```

Here is full description in Android documentation: [MediaRecorder | Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)

Below is part of my code which I am using & it is working :)

```
if(what==MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED)
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.reset();

    // Flag to recording (in my code I am using to stop/start capturing)
    recording = false;
    recording = true;

    initRecorder();
    prepareRecorder();

    recorder.start();

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // 5 000 ms - 5 s
    // 300 000 ms - 5 min
}
```

To set Max Duration you need to declare:

```
recorder.setMaxDuration(300000);
```

in `initRecorder()` function.
I recommend you also read this: [`SetMaxDuration`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227122/mediarecorder-setmaxdurationint-timer-what-happens-when-timer-expires)

I hope that what I wrote will help you.

Comment: Will there be gaps (near second or two) in video while you start/stop it?

Comment: did you able to get a solution to reduce the gap