# Android: Camera2 - Reducing delay between video chunks/segments during continuous video recording

Tags: android, android-camera2, mediarecorder, video-recording

I am currently working on an android app that continuously records video using the camera2 API while segmenting it into 1-minute chunks.

My requirement is that the chunks/segments of 1 minute should be seamlessly merged at a later stage.

At the moment I am able to achieve saving in chunks by setting up a timer to restart recording at the end of the time period:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Inside timer")
            if (!stopRecording) recordSession() else cancel()
        }
    }, 0, duration)
```

where duration is the length of the clip that I need.
The recording is done using mediaRecorder that outputs to a different file every time it is initialized.

At the end of all this, if I merge the videos there is a noticeable break in the video (few frames lost) and a bit of audio is also skipped, making it quite evident that the video "jumped".

Please let me know how this can be made seamless.

P.S. I have already seen the grafika examples (no audio and it is using camera1 API and not camera2)
I've also seen a few SO posts like
[Android: Split video during capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264592/android-split-video-during-capture)
but the delay is still not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it to be seamless, you need to investigate MediaRecorder's own time limit options, or possibly have to build things from the lower-level API objects of MediaCodec and MediaMuxer.

Specifically, look at [setNextOutputFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setNextOutputFile(java.io.File)) and [setMaxOutputDuration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setMaxDuration(int)).  That should allow you to automatically transition between files, with a specific length for each snippet.  That will hopefully be seamless.

If not, some combination of a MediaCodec and one or more MediaMuxers should let you build this, but that's a lot of stuff to wire together correctly.

Comment: Thank you Eddy. I am trying to explore your suggestion and trying to use setNextOutputFile.
However, I am getting an IllegalStateException on 
`private val recorderInfoListener by lazy { MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener { mr, what, extra ->
        if(what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED){
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {                 **mr.setNextOutputFile(newPartFile())**
                Log.d(TAG, "Output file changed")
            }
        }
    } }`
I can't seem to figure this out since this is long after prepare() call

Comment: I think the issue I was facing is because `setNextOutputFile` is supposed to be used `maxfilesize`.

as for you second suggestion, could you please guild me to some example code that makes use of this? I think grafika uses some of this but its not with audio and the recording is distorted more over it is using the older camera API.

Thank you

Comment: Hi @eddy-talvala, first - thank you for your answers they helped me alot. Second, I use media muxers but I still lose on some phones 1 video frame every 5 minutes. What should i do?