# Record voice for 5 minutes in android

Tags: android

I need to record user voice in android for 5 minutes. When user click a button, then start recording and stop immediately after 5 minutes. How do I do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If supported by the hardware, then you can use use the MediaRecorder APIs for recording the audio.

Checkout the following link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Comment: But how do I set a timer of 5 minutes ?

Comment: For this, you can use the setMaxDuration method of MediaRecorder, and implement the onInfoListener, in which you can verify the flag MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED, and stop the recording when it's true. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227122/mediarecorder-setmaxdurationint-timer-what-happens-when-timer-expires.

Answer (score 0):

This link give a good example : http://www.discretelogix.com/blog/android-articles/how-to-record-audio-files-in-android
To record for only 5 minutes, you can set a timer which will start when you click on the button and which will trigger the end of the recording after 5 minutes.