# Set time limit on audio recording in android

Tags: android, multithreading, button, touch

I created a button which while touched starts recording and when not touched stops recording voice. Shall I implement a thread like this? but where exactly shall I place it, in ACTION.DOWN or ACTION.UP ?

```
public class StopRecord extends Thread {
int i = 0;
@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stopRecording();
        }
    });
}
```

}

which I have to place it inside here:

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startRecording();
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    stopRecording();
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I guess you're trying to use startRecording() and stopRecording on worker thread. But the handler you use isn't defined in your worker thread. So the methods will still run on main thread.

Comment: So.. any complete example because I am confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the example code, but I suggest checking out the developer guide which gives a good example, check this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

For the timeout part, check this : [MediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(int timer) what happens when timer expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227122/mediarecorder-setmaxdurationint-timer-what-happens-when-timer-expires)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
           if(MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED > A vALUE) 
            { stoprecording}
        }
    }; this what you mean?

Comment: Check this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener.html#onInfo(android.media.MediaRecorder, int, int). It can be used to stop the recording once you reach your specified timeout.

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sence that you create a button. When you press it, the recording starts and the button changes (text, maybe background color) to tell the user that a recording is in progress. When he presses it again, it stops. You can make a timeout with a handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayMs). But if the user presses the stop button before the timeout, you should cancel the handler. You do that by handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)

Answer (score 0):

So I did additionally this:

```
private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {

        if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
            //display in long period of time
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "End Recording", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            stopRecording();

        }

    }
};
```