# How can I safely use MediaRecorder to capture a specific duration of media?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I want to capture 5 seconds of audio and save it using `android.media.MediaRecorder`. One approach would be to call `start()` and schedule `stop()` to be called with a `android.os.Handler`, but I'm not sure that would be very precise.

`MediaRecorder` has a [`setMaxDuration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setMaxDuration(int)) method which looks hopeful. It will send a message to the `android.media.MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener` once the timer is up, but the docs say:

> Stopping happens asynchronously, there is no guarantee that the
>   recorder will have stopped by the time the listener is notified.

I believe I need to call `release()` on the `MediaRecorder` when I'm done, so I need to know when it's safe to do so.

So:

- the max duration isn't mentioned in the [state transition diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html). Is it necessary to call `stop()`?
- am I right in assuming that the recorder will save the audio and flush the file when the maximum duration is up? Flushing / finalising the file isn't mentioned in the docs.
- is it actually necessary to call `release()` after if I'm not reusing the `MediaRecorder` object?
- should I assume that it's unsafe to call `release()` as part of the `OnInfoListener` because of the asynchrony?
- if so, how should I do this? Set another timer?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, the `setMaxDuration` method looks promising, although the fact that stopping capture occurs asynchronously leaves some speculation as to the actual performance. It might be worthwhile to test this method out and see how much the desired capture time differs from the actual capture time. As a side note, it should not be necessary to call `stop()` when using this method. Also, since `setMaxDuration` is essentially just a scheduled call to `stop()`, I think it is safe to assume that it will also handle the flushing/finalizing.

If you discover that this method is too inaccurate to be useful then you could use a simple `CountDownTimer` to schedule your recording interval. This class is nice because the tick is synchronized, which means that your timing intervals will be accurate to within a few milliseconds; much more accurate than trying to schedule a `Handler`. You could try something like the following:

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.release();
    }
}
.start();
```

The above example schedules a 5s `CountDownTimer` with 1s ticks. When the 5 seconds has elapsed, `stop()` and `release()` will be called, respectively. If you wanted to make it even more accurate you could add a simple counter inside of the `onTick()` method and then place all of your `MediaRecorder` calls in there. For example, if you were to set the `CountDownTimer` to 7 seconds, still with 1 second ticks, then on the first tick you would call `start()`, assuming you have already prepared the recording; then, five ticks later you would call `stop()` and `release()`. This would be quite accurate since, according to the `CountDownTimer` API:

> the calls to `onTick(long)` are synchronized to this object

In regards to calling `release()`, it is recommended to call this method even if you do not plan on reusing the object. Per the API documentation, failing to release the `MediaRecorder` instance could cause a resource/battery drain:

> In addition to unnecessary resources (such as memory and instances of
>   codecs) being held, failure to call this method immediately if a
>   MediaRecorder object is no longer needed may also lead to continuous
>   battery consumption for mobile devices, and recording failure for
>   other applications if no multiple instances of the same codec are
>   supported on a device.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try it out. Any ideas about the safety of releasing on the async callback?

Comment: While it is asynchronous, I believe as long as you make sure to call `stop()` before you call `release()` you should be okay.

Comment: But isn't that the whole question about the async event, that it will call `stop()` itself and I don't know if that will have happened before the callback?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I do not believe that `MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener` will automatically call `stop()`. Per the API definition, it is "callback to be invoked when an error occurs while recording." I think `stop()` has to be called manually. There is more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227122/mediarecorder-setmaxdurationint-timer-what-happens-when-timer-expires

Comment: I understand your question now. I just saw that `MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener` is triggered by `MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED` - I missed this the first time I read about the listener. So even though `setMaxDuration` is supposed to automatically call `stop()` it doesn't seem like it does. The API guide is a little ambiguous about this.

Comment: It is ambiguous isn't it? I thought I'd misread the docs. I'll try it out and report back.