# Video recording intent with time limit never stops at given time limit on android O

Tags: android, android-intent, android-8.0-oreo

I am launching video recording intent with time duration limit. It works fine on every device, But on android O, it never stops at given time. Tested devices are Nexus 5X, Nexus 6P, Pixel. All of these have android O.

```
public static void videoCaptureActivity(Activity activity, Uri filePath, int durationLimit ){                
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, filePath);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, durationLimit * 60);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, ViewConstants.KEY_VIDEO_CAPTURE_CODE);
         }
```

I checked the logs what I found is not helping, Though I am sharing it:

```
08-18 11:36:07.511 3136-10386/? E/mm-camera-sensor: port_sensor_handle_aec_update:444miss aec update window, skip
08-18 11:36:08.111 3396-1469/? D/WificondControl: Scan result ready event
08-18 11:36:08.352 3396-3426/? I/zygote64: Background concurrent copying GC freed 73915(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 42% free, 16MB/28MB, paused 656us total 202.501ms
08-18 11:36:10.379 8360-9342/? E/VideoRecPreImp2: onMaxDuration 60018
08-18 11:36:12.381 356-356/? W//system/bin/hwservicemanager: getTransportFromManifest: Cannot find entry android.hardware.graphics.mapper@2.0::IMapper in either framework or device manifest, using default transport.
08-18 11:36:12.387 10718-10718/? I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8992.so from the current namespace instead.
```

It just says `"E/VideoRecPreImp2: onMaxDuration 60018"` which is not helpful at all. Is it possible that the attribute for setting time limit has been changed for O? But I checked [Android-O Preview API](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html) , There is no such info. Has anyone faced this issue ?

**Update:**

Just now tested on Nexus 6 with 7.1.1 and Nexus 5 with 6.0 , on Nexus 6 it is working fine but not on Nexus 5. Is it something related to GoogleCamera ?

Comment: I have tested with Pixel AVD with API 26(v4), its working fine and yes if the time is >60s then you will get count down only when the last 60s is there.

Comment: Did you try using MediaRecorder ?? instead to record videos

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, But do you have any O real device ? Because for video recording intent, it would be good to test on real device. @DwlRathod

Comment: @OmarDanisha No and I don't want to use custom Camera.

Comment: please refer here I think it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/4362411/3872374

Comment: @OmarDanisha Man I won't be having access of MediaRecorder when I'll use video intent. So that link is not useful at all.

Comment: NO , I just Showed you another approach .

Comment: See Camera API has many changes lately, managing all these APIs will be pain in the ass. Also we're not developing a Camera based app. So for me it is pointless to use custom one. Because if any changes happens in future, there will be a maintenance cost which we want to avoid anyway. @OmarDanisha